# Is Open Data significantly different from the proposed Open Science site on Area 51?

Tags: discussion

There is a proposal on Stack Exchange Area 51 for a new site called [Open Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65426/open-science). A [question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13455/merge-stem-review-with-open-science) was raised there about merging, which mentioned in passing the idea of merging with the Open Data site, and I wanted to know how contributers to Open Data view this.

Are there specific differences that should keep the sites separate?

What are the prospects for a site that invites questions on freely available open data **and** freely available open research papers?

Comment: open science is open data, but open data does not have to be open science. both are components of openness.

Answer (score 6):

As a moderator on the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), I can see some value to having separate sites in that some open science questions would not involve data issues. For example, the idea of openly sharing science results (other than data) would not be part of an open data Q&A. In the same way, Q&A on the policies behind the release of open data or a data normalization issue may not be well received in Open Science.

On the other hand, it takes a HUGE amount of effort to lift up and get people involved in a new Stack Exchange, and if there's a way to work together, that would be great!

([Cross-posted](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13455/merge-stem-review-with-open-science))

Comment: I can see why some questions from each site might not fit the other. Assuming the two sites don't agree on a joint umbrella title to allow them to join into one site, what other ways are there of being mutually beneficial? I like your hint at there being a way to work together. If anyone has any ideas that would be great. Are sites in beta ever allowed a question migration agreement between each other?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how we can work together without losing the identity of both sites. Obviously, non of the two titles could stand alone with the content of both sites. In my eyes, the only way to work together is to merge the two sites. This means to make a "lifting" in Open Data site to accept Open Science's content as well.

Comment: Other ways to collaborate are to reference questions between the sites, and encourage people to participate in both as appropriate.

Comment: I think one big aspect of Open Science is data and therefore much of what they are about is Open Data. But there is much here at Open Data that is non-scientific.

Comment: @JeanneHolm So, we are talking about an unofficial way without any written part that these two sites are collaborate? If we have the open science in the options to flag for migration and vice versa I believe that it easier than find an official way to merge the two sites.

Comment: I think at this time flagging the migration of questions or referencing the questions that are appropriate in both places may be the easiest way.